# trycatch error handling and for loops error

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, error-handling, try-catch

Having trouble handling errors in a for loop because of the scope in the tryCatch error function, I imagine.

The error handles correctly in the sense that it skips and continues working, but whats in the error function doesn't write into the data frame (d), thus when an error ocurrs, I get an output with the number of row, instead of NULLS or NA's.

What am I missing? This is a visual example of the loops taking place.

```
function<-function(vector){

n<-length(vector)
d<-data.frame(a=1:n,
              b=1:n,
              c=1:n)
for (i in 1:n)
{ 
tryCatch({
  #create an m for every i in vector
  m<-foo(i)

  for (j in 1:length(m[,1]))
  { #for every element in m, transform with a function
    m[j]<-foo2(j) 
  }

  #now, with m transformed, fill every element of d (so that it matches elements of vector)
  d[i,]$a = sum(m)
  d[i,]$b = sd(m)
  d[i,]$c = mean(m)

  #end try
  }, error = function(e){
  #if there is an erorr in m<-foo(i), I want it to place NULL or NA values in each column of d
    d[i,]$a = NULL
    d[i,]$b = NULL
    d[i,]$c = NULL
}
#end trycatch
)
  #end loop
}
  #end function
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could post a sample data.